# JavaScript work only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I face with some problem. I have page and make auto refresh div(table) content everything works fine and i have table with filters from javascript, but after refresh filters gone. I try call again filters function but nothing happen.

Why dont work filterJS() again with setInterval script?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Main Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="filter/tablefilter.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="refresh">
<table id="tab" class="my" >
 <tr>
  <th>World Regions</th>
  <th>Population ( 2007 Est.)</th>
  <th>Population % of World</th>
  <th>Internet Usage, Latest Data</th>
  <th>% Population ( Penetration )</th>
  <th>Usage % of World</th>
  <th>Usage Growth 2000-2007</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Africa</td>
  <td>933,448,292</td>
  <td>14.2 %</td>
  <td>32,765,700</td>
  <td>3.5 %</td>
  <td>3.0 %</td>
  <td>625.8%</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Asia</td>
  <td>3,712,527,624</td>
  <td>56.5 %</td>
  <td>389,392,288</td>
  <td>10.5 %</td>
  <td>35.6 %</td>
  <td>240.7 %</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Europe</td>
  <td>809,624,686</td>
  <td>12.3 %</td>
  <td>312,722,892</td>
  <td>38.6 %</td>
  <td>28.6 %</td>
  <td>197.6 %</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Middle East</td>
  <td>193,452,727</td>
  <td>2.9 %</td>
  <td>19,382,400</td>
  <td>10.0 %</td>
  <td>1.8 %</td>
  <td>490.1 %</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
function filterJS(){
 var table2_Props =  {     
     col_0: "select",
     col_5: "none",
     display_all_text: " [ Show all ] ",
     sort_select: true
    };
 setFilterGrid( "tab",table2_Props );}
//]]>

filterJS();

 $(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
            filterJS();
   $('.refresh').load(document.URL +  ' .refresh');}, 2000);
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you are calling the function before the Ajax call returns the data....

Comment: Yes include, it works fine if page start but after setInterval div content changes, but filter not

Answer (score 2):

Call it after the table is updated, use the callback argument that load() provides

```
setInterval(function() { $('#myTable').load(document.URL +  ' #myTable', filterJS);}, 2000);
```

and you really should look into using setTimeout and not interval so if the server takes awhile to respond, the calls do not start to pile up.

```
function filterJS() {
    var table2_Props = {
        col_0: "select",
        col_1: "select",
        col_3: "none",
        display_all_text: " [ All ] ",
        sort_select: true
    };
    setFilterGrid("myTable", table2_Props);
    window.setTimeout(reloadData, 2000);
};

function reloadData() {
    $('#myTable').load(document.URL + ' #myTable', filterJS);
}
```

Comment: Still dont work i edit my code and upload in question.

Comment: Your updated code still does not call the filter function when the table is updated...

Comment: I try put filterJS(); after .load still nothing :(

Comment: Seeing you type `filterJS();` makes me think you did not do it right. Show the code you tried.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
   $('.refresh').load(document.URL +  ' .refresh', filterJS);}, 2000);//1 try
   filterJS();// 2 try
 });

Answer (score 0):

Set it up to call the function recursively in the callback, and use `setTimeout` instead of interval

```
function getTable() {
  $('#myTable').load(document.URL + ' #myTable', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      getTable();
    }, 2000)
  });
}
```

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/pagiyo/1/edit?js,console,output) showing it working fine. Try doing some console logs to find out where you're going wrong. Bare in mind, `load` will replace HTML, not append to it.

Comment: Maybe it work gettable() function, but filters show only one time then dissapear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delay the script to ensure the filters run AFTER the table is loaded, it will only work until your network is slow... so quite a bad way of doing it. Instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myTable').load(document.URL +  ' #myTable', function() {
          filterJS();
      });
});
```

This way you use a callback function which will execute every time after the load is complete.

Add your recursion accordingly.